# Cron jobs no longer work since installing ssl cert on rackspace cloud server

Tags: ssl, cron, rackspace

I recently installed an ssl cert on my rackspace cloud server.  Prior to installing it, my cron jobs were running fine.

When I ssh to my server and do a crontab -l,

I can see the jobs are still there:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/curl https://mydomain.com/crons/do_things.php
```

if I directly visit the file in my broswer it still works.

So I'm wondering if there is anything special I need to set up or change to have my cron job running again?

Comment: Have you tried running `/usr/bin/curl https://mydomain.com/crons/do_things.php` from the CLI?

Comment: ahhh, ya, once I saw the warning it was an easy fix.  I didn't know I could just do it from the cli, I thought it had to be in my cron file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell curl to ignore any ssl warning with -k option. Most likely it is the ssl warning which is stopping it from being executed automatically. The caveat is curl with perform "insecure" SSL  connections  and  transfers.

/usr/bin/curl -k https://mydomain.com/crons/do_things.php